# How to return header with view in codeigniter 4

Tags: xml, codeigniter, content-type, sitemap, codeigniter-4

I am trying to make a sitemap in codeigniter 4. But I don't know how to set the content type to text/xml.
I have tried using the following code

```
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return view('frontend/sitemap/sitemap', $this->data);
```

I get an error that below is the rendering of the page.
I have checked all the documentation but i have not been able to figure out the problem

Comment: return $this->response->setXML($data);

Comment: Ok but then how will i return the view

Comment: you can use renderstring and encode it to json than send it